# Get category of post inside save_post hook

Tags: functions, categories, hooks, save-post

I don't have much experience with hooks in WordPress so i have found a problem who don't look too difficult, but i can't find the answer.

In my project i have a metabox who will get the content after i make a category check inside my save_post hook.

But now i can't get the category selected and i don't know how can i know that info.

I'm using `get_the_category($post_id)` inside my hook, but this don't return my category.

My function is this below (and i got this from other question here):

```
function updatePost( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    // Stop anything from happening if revision
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'updatePost' );

    // get post type
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );

    // run codes based on post status
    $post_status = get_post_status();
    if ( $post_status != 'draft' )  {
        if ( isset( $_POST['img-destacada'] ) ) {
            get_the_category($post_id);
            // here i will put some logic to set the $img value based on my category
            $img = '';
            update_post_meta($post_id, "img-destacada", $img);
        }
    }

    // re-hook this function
    add_action( 'save_post', 'updatePost', 100, 3 );
}
```

How can i get the category info to then set the $img value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code calls `get_the_category()` but it doesn't use the value returned.

```
// ...
if ( isset( $_POST['img-destacada'] ) ) {
    $categories = get_the_category($post_id);
    $img = '';
    // $categories should contain either an array of WP_Term objects,
    // or an empty array.
    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
        // Here I've used the slug of the first item in the array to set the $img.
        // You may have other logic you want to use.
        $img = $categories[0]->slug . '.jpg'; 
    }
    if ( ! empty( $img ) ) {
        // Checks to make sure there's an $img set.
        update_post_meta($post_id, "img-destacada", $img);
    }
}
// ...
```

### References

- [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)
- [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/)

Comment: Thank you! This works!